# How to change background color of Stepper widget to transparent color?

Tags: flutter

Stepper widget's background color is transparent at the Vertical type. When change type like StepperType.horizontal, stepper has white-grey background color. How could I change that background color at the horizontal axis?

> Here is my sample code:

```
Container(
   width: _width,
   child: Stepper(
      type: StepperType.horizontal,
      steps: [
        Step(
          title: Text("First"),
          content: Text("This is our first example."),
        ),
        Step(
          title: Text("Second"),
          content: Text("This is our second example."),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a picture of the color you're referring to. Here both axes have an equal background.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change the background color of stepper widget wrap it into Theme and give it a color in Canvas color.

```
Container(
        width: _width,
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.lightBlue),
          child: Stepper(
            type: StepperType.horizontal,
            steps: [
              Step(
                title: Text("First"),
                content: Text("This is our first example."),
              ),
              Step(
                title: Text("Second"),
                content: Text("This is our second example."),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: It worked but I wrote a widget that overrides Stepper widget and added backgroundColor property. I think Stepper widget was not well coded. I hope Flutter team will improve it with next update.

Comment: After change stepper type "StepperType.vertical" theme does not work.

Comment: but that changes the color of all of them

Comment: After many searches and desperately needed this worked for me, the only way that worked for the BACKGROUND, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in the stepper package of flutter to customize the stepper. You can find the stepper package in the *External Libraries/Dart packages/Flutter/src/material/stepper.dart*. Here is the look now:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score -1):

You could try to add :

```
Container(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    ...
),
```

Comment: It is not a solution. Stepper's color overrides Container's color.